# How to CAD: smooth width transition in sheet-metal bends

Tags: design, cad, bending, metal-folding, metalwork

I am working with FreeCAD 0.20 and Sheet Metal work bench 0.2.63, but universal CAD tips are also welcomed. As shown in the image, I would like to bend sheet metal with smoothly chancing width along the bend. So, I cannot use for example negative extend values causing stair-like features, unless the sharp transitions could be smoothed somehow afterwards. Any ideas?

Edit: I also tried the Sketch On Sheet metal tool, but it removes material appropriately only if the sketched cuts are fully within the sheet. If the cuts go over the edges the cuts become erratic.[image: Visualization about intended sheet-metal bend.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tip I got elsewhere is to first make the flat sheet with appropriate width transitions, then bend it afterwards. I'll give this approach a try. Other tips are still welcomed, just in case.

Comment: why would you be asking for additionsl tips when your question has been answered by you?

Comment: @jsotola with the described approach I need to start from beginning with one part that was almost designed otherwise. Shaping the bends afterwards would be more straightforward in general. The second reason are the not-so-positive experiences with FreeCAD. For example, if the proposed approach leads to a bug and dead end.

Comment: A common workflow in SolidWorks is to unfold the flat pattern, do additional features, and then refold it. Does FreeCAD have this function?

Comment: @jonathanrswift Aha, an interesting approach. Yes, it should be possible in FreeCAD as well. Thanks for the tip.